# How can I redirect subprocess's output to a file while still printing to the subprocess's console?

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7

I have an application and in this application I run a separate Windows application that spawns its own terminal. When this separate application runs I can redirect the output to a file as shown below

```
process = subprocess.Popen([self.app, self.app_s],
                           stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

for line in iter(process.stdout.readline, ''):
   print(line)    
   file.write(line)

process.wait()
```

However, if I do this I can no longer print to the subprocess's console and I can only print to the main application's console.

Is there a way I can continue to see the output in the subprocess's console while also logging the output to a file?

Comment: you can redirect it to the stderr for example

Comment: Just like in a shell, if you want to map content to multiple destinations, you need a piece of software to read it and then make extra copies. (In a shell script that's usually done by the program `tee`, but since you're writing Python, you can of course use Python code for the purpose).

Comment: What do you mean, "separate console"? Is this something like a Windows program that spawns its own terminal? (Over in the UNIX world, a program inherits its stdout descriptor from its parent process, so if the parent doesn't override the child's stdout to go to something like a pipe, they both go to the _same_ terminal/"console"/etc).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Yeah it's a Window's program that spawns it's own terminal. I'd like to continue to output in that terminal even after piping stdout.

Answer (score 0):

In the following manner, you can write to all the places you want.

```
process = subprocess.Popen([self.app, self.app_s],
                           stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    
for line in proc.stdout:
        sys.stdout.write(line)
        file.write(line)
```